# What are the properties of the partially polarized light on refraction?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, polarization, refraction

When a ray of ordinary light is passed on the water's surface, the reflected light will be completely polarized (vibrations in one plane).

My question is what will be the **plane of vibration in the partially polarized light** that undergoes refraction? **How many planes of vibration** will be there? A deep explanation focusing on the partially polarized light's **planes of vibration** would be appreciated.

Comment: Only when the incidence angle is the Brewster's angle is reflected light completely polarized.

Answer (score 3):

The reflected light is not completely polarised. It's certainly true that $s$ polarised light (i.e. light polarised in the plane of the surface) is more strongly reflected, but except at the [Brewsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle) angle $p$ polarised light is reflected as well.

The plane of polarisation of $s$ and $p$ polarised light is not changed by reflection/transmission, however a mixture of polarisations will be changed because the $s$ to $p$ ratio of the reflected and transmitted light will not be the same as the incident light.

The reflection and transmission of the light can be calculated using the [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel%27s_equations). The link I've given is to the Wikipedia article Fresnel equations and this is an excellent starting point if you want a thorough explanation of the subject. To go much farther you'll need a good book on Optics. My favourite is "Optics" by Hecht and Zajac, though I think that can be hard to find these days.

Comment: Hecht isn't hard to find. It's still one of the standards.

Comment: @ColinK ...although Alfred Zajac somehow dropped off along the way - don't know what happenned there.